# NGUI Button Click Event Issue in UNITY3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to try to get button name whenever clicks on button.I did a sample but doesn't work with arg value but it works successfully without arg value.I am new to UNITY3D.So please see the below code and suggest me what to do?

Code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IG : MonoBehaviour 
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Debug.Log (" **** Start() **** ");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    //TODO :: Button Click event
    public void IGBtn(string BtnName)
    {
        Debug.Log (" **** IGBtn Clicked **** "+BtnName);
    }
}
```

Error is :

```
MissingMethodException: The best match for method IGBtn has some invalid parameter.
System.MonoType.InvokeMember (System.String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object target, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.String[] namedParameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoType.cs:520)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMember (System.Object behaviour, System.String name, System.Object variable) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:19)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
UIButtonMessage:Send() (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/Interaction/UIButtonMessage.cs:77)
UIButtonMessage:OnClick() (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/Interaction/UIButtonMessage.cs:56)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:680)
UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1194)
UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:948)
UICamera:Update() (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:803)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that the signature for the method Unity/NGUI is trying to invoke has no parameters.

How did you tell NGUI to call that method on button click?

It's been a long while since I've used NGUI, but it seems like the way to get a capture a click event is to have a script on the button that has a method OnClick(). By nature of the script being on that button you have access to the button that was clicked (this.gameObject.name). Also, according to these [docs](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=160) you can use UICamera.currentTouchID to get the id of the button that was clicked.